# sql view using group sum with splitting shipping charges based on number of items in the order

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

Need to create a sql view for calculating the commission & shipping charges. Shipping charges are charged on order id level and I need the cost calculation on order item id level. Please have a look at the image attached. Pls note as shipping charges are at order id level.And not at order item id level. Order item id column is blank for shipping charges row.

[SQL VIEW IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46cRr.png)

create table code for fiddle

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`T` (`order_id` varchar(19),
    `order_item_id` varchar(14), `type` varchar(17), `description`
    varchar(16), `amount` int(3)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
    INSERT INTO `test`.`T` (`order_id`, `order_item_id`, `type`,
   `description`, `amount`) VALUES ('171-7045714-5715521', '51516304093723', 'ItemPrice', 'Principal', 200),
    ('171-7045714-5715521', '51516304093723', 'ItemFees', 'Commission', -16),
    ('171-7045714-5715521', '17035541556323', 'ItemPrice', 'Principal', 450),
    ('171-7045714-5715521', '17035541556323', 'ItemFees', 'Commission', -36),
    ('171-7045714-5715521', '', 'other-transaction', 'Shipping Charges', -55);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT T.order_id,
    T.order_item_id,
    total
        + COALESCE((SELECT SUM(amount) FROM Orders_Detail AS OD
                  WHERE OD.order_id = T.order_id
                            AND type = 'other_transaction'), 0)
          / 
          COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders_Detail AS OD
                  WHERE OD.order_id = T.order_id
                            AND type = 'ItemPrice'), 1) 
FROM
    (SELECT OD.order_id,
           OD.order_item_id,
           SUM(amount) total
    FROM Orders_Detail AS OD
    WHERE OD.order_item_id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY OD.order_id, 
             OD.order_item_id) AS T
```

Comment: it is giving a error #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: I've changed ISNULL function to COALESCE

Comment: I am learner. Thanks for your help. pls correct me if wrong. T is my table what is Orders_Details it is giving error. Have add the create code for the table

Comment: Change Orders_Detail table name to yours table name (T)

Comment: `SELECT t.order_id, t.order_item_id, total + COALESCE((SELECT SUM(amount) FROM t AS OD WHERE OD.order_id = t.order_id AND type = 'other_transaction'), 0) / COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t AS OD WHERE OD.order_id = t.order_id AND type = 'ItemPrice'), 1) FROM (SELECT OD.order_id, OD.order_item_id, SUM(amount) total FROM t AS OD WHERE OD.order_item_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY OD.order_id, OD.order_item_id) AS t`                                                  Able to run the query but result is incorrect it is not dividing the shipping charges are per the order_id

Answer (score 0):

SQL syntax may change by vendor, but the following should work in MS SQL SERVER minor variations for other version, mainly use a different function for COALSCE:

```
CREATE VIEW myView as 
   SELECT main.order_id, main.order_item_id, COALESCE(P.a,0) + COALESCE(C.a,0) - (COALESCE(S.a,0) / main.c) AS price
   FROM 
         (((SELECT order_id, order_item_id, count(*) as c FROM orderTable GROUP BY order_id, order_item_id) main LEFT OUTER JOIN
         (SELECT amount AS a FROM orderTable WHERE description='Principal') P ON main.order_id =P.order_id AND main.order_item_id = P.order_item_id)  LEFT OUTER JOIN
         (SELECT amount AS a FROM orderTable WHERE description='Commission') C ON main.order_id=C.order_id AND main.order_item_id = C.order_item_id)  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT amount AS a FROM orderTable WHERE description='Shipping Charges') S ON main.order_id=S.order_id AND main.order_item_id = S.order_item_id
```

Comment: using 5.7.9 it gives a error   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') + COALESCE(C.a,0) - (COALESCE(S.a,0) / main.c) AS price
   FROM 
         ((' at line 2

Comment: Try now, it was missing a zero

Comment: it first gave a error unknown table "orderTabIe" changed orderTable  as main. Now giving a error #1054 - Unknown column 'P.order_id' in 'on clause'